# React-apollo/Graphql: Display results from DB

Tags: reactjs, graphql, create-react-app, react-apollo, graphql-js

My goal for the last week has been to display items in the array received from a query executed when the submit button is clicked. I am using the following function and calling it from the render function:

```
displayElements() {
    var data = this.props.getObjectsQuery;
    console.log(this.props);
    if (data.loading) {
        return <option disabled>Loading...</option>;
    } else {
        return data.action.map(action => {
            return (<option key={action.action} value={action.timestamp}>{action.filename}</option>);

        })
    }
}
```

Console.log shows the following data:

```
data: {action: [{action: "User Assist Changed", timestamp: 1499348050000,…}
```

But nothing is seen in the browser.

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Nothing is showing in the browser.

Comment: The console is showing data.

Comment: Is data.action an empty array?

Comment: This is what shows up in the console: data: {action: [{action: "User Assist Changed", timestamp: 1499348050000,…}

Comment: You are accessing `this.props.getObjectsQuery` instead of `this.props.data`

Comment: Tried that but same problem.

Comment: props updated in react dev tools tab?

Comment: Yes. I can see data: {action: [{action: "User Assist Changed", timestamp: 1499348050000,…}

Comment: then use `shouldComponentUpdate` to force rerender - react don't do this alone, it reacts to state changes, not props

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: So, you are saying use this function to display the contents in the array that I'm seeing displayed in the console?